# Show an error on a label box for invalid username or password

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

This is my code. How to write the code label box. I am selecting data from two different table for each table it ll redirect to two different pages.
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var qry = (from test in je.employee
                   where test.emp_email.Equals(TxtUserName.Text) & 
                         test.emp_pass.Equals(TxtPassword.Text)
                   select test).FirstOrDefault();

```
        if (null != qry)
        {
            Response.Redirect("EmployeeHome.aspx");
        }           
        else 
        {
            var qry2 = (from test1 in je.employer
                        where test1.c_mail.Equals(TxtUserName.Text) & 
                              test1.c_pass.Equals(TxtPassword.Text)
                        select test1).FirstOrDefault();
            if (null != qry2)
            {
                Response.Redirect("EmployerHome.aspx");
            }
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var qry = (from test in  je.employee
                  where test.emp_email.Equals(TxtUserName.Text) & test.emp_pass.Equals(TxtPassword.Text)
                   select test).FirstOrDefault();
   var qry2 = (from test1 in je.employer
                    where test1.c_mail.Equals(TxtUserName.Text) & test1.c_pass.Equals(TxtPassword.Text)
                    select test1).FirstOrDefault();
    if (null!=qry)
    {
        Response.Redirect("EmployeeHome.aspx");
    }
    else if(null != qry2)
    {
         Response.Redirect("EmployerHome.aspx");          
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Incorrect username or password!";
    }
```

Comment: no no.. the login workin fine. I am askin if the login failed a label box ll appear in the page and promt "invalid data".. How to mplement that on this code

Comment: as u can see i already used a else condition. so its showin me a error

Comment: hey it is only redirecting to EmployeeHome.aspx what about EmployerHome.aspx..?